# $http promise executes success block even when service returns 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I'm confused or may be didn't understand how angular promise works. I am trying to write some code blocks for my error handling but I see it's always executing success block in my controller. However I've written success and error block in my service too because I need some transformation in my response. I see it's executing error block in service which is perfectly fine but the same promise executes success block in my controller.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
         <h1>{{data}}</h1>
    </div>
<div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('services', []).service('myService', function($http) {
   this.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
      },function(data) {
       console.log("Error block of service");
      });
   }
});


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    // Call the getData and set the response "data" in your scope.  
    myService.getData().then(function(myReponseData) {
        console.log("Success block of controller");
        $scope.data = myReponseData;
    },function(data) {
        console.log("Error block of controller");
        $scope.data = "Error " + data;
    });
}]);
```

I reproduce the same issue in fiddle. Have a look [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prtAP/334/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how `Promise` is designed to work.

If you return anything inside of the `catch` block, whatever you return becomes a `success` for the next link in the chain.

The only two ways around that are:

1. Rethrow an error inside of your catch
2. Return a rejected Promise inside of your catch

Here's a simpler example:

```
Promise.reject(5)
  .catch(x => x * 2)
  .catch(err => console.log("THIS NEVER FIRES"))
  .then(x => console.log("Value is: ", x));
  // => "Value is: 10"

Promise.reject(5)
  .catch(x => Promise.reject(x * 2))
  .then(x => console.log("THIS NEVER FIRES"))
  .catch(err => console.log("Error is:", err));
  // => "Error is: 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

In rejection handlers, it is important to **re-throw errors.** Otherwise the rejected promise will be **converted** to a successful promise:

```
angular.module('services', []).service('myService', function($http) {
   this.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
      },function(errorResponse) {
        console.log("Error block of service");
        //IMPORTANT re-throw error 
        throw errorResponse;
      });
   }
});
```

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).